# How can I "standarize" values to better visualize a cloropleth map?

Tags: python-3.x, visualization, geopandas

This is a cloropleth map that I have done. It displays the number of IPs by each dictrict. The higher the number of IPs the darker the district's color. But as it can be seen the values vary a lot (max_value=8024, min_value=0). So it is not possible to see a clear 'image' of the data.

[image]

I thought of normalizing/standarizing the data. So far I have tried:

a) MIN-MAX

```
max_count=new_df['count'].max()
min_count=new_df['count'].min()

new_df['count']=(new_df['count'] - (min_count)) / (max_count - min_count)

new_df
```

[image]

But as it can be seen, the colormap scale has changed but not the map. 
So, are there any techniques to improve the visulization of this map?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
`new_df.plot(column='count', cmap='OrRd', scheme='quantiles');`